# Acces Token management in Google Drive api for Javascript

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-drive-api

My application using *JavaScript* to connect to get access the Google drive API.(see https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js). First time it ask the user permission. At the time Google may give *access_token* to my application. I want to use the token to access the Google drive data in future(That time the user may not be sign-in in Google account). Is it possible? if possible how to do?
Is it possible to the application to ask Google "please I want to get permission of the user user@example.com"? It will be useful at the time of multiple-signing

**EDIT**: Exactly my question is "Offline access is possible in JavaScript-API?" See It is possible in PHP-API: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript API uses the OAuth 2.0 Client flow which only returns an access token. If you set `approval_prompt=auto` in your request URL,  the consent page for a given set of scopes will only be shown the first time the user goes through the sequence, so he will not have to grant access to your app again:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent

Comment: The access_token will expire soon, right? If he is visiting after loging out of Google, what will happen? Google will ask him to log-in, right? I want to avoid it. Irrespective of Google-log-in-Session, I want to get access of Google Drive. Is there anyway to get long-lived-token? Is it possible only in server-flow (eg:- PHP API) only?

Comment: You may want to use an application-owned account and not on a user’s Drive. Check service accounts at https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts

Comment: I don't want application-owned accounts. Exactly my question is "Offline access is possible in JavaScript-API?" See It is possible in PHP-API: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Comment: Offline access is not possible, the Javascript API can only use the Client flow

Comment: Thanks alot. It helped me to understand more about client flow. Good Night.

Comment: the `approval_prompt=auto` does not seem to be feature on the linked page.  @ClaudioCherubino could you update your answer to api v3